# MySQL - Converting Latin1 data to UTF8MB4 is changing and/or adding in "?"

Tags: mysql, data-conversion

So we are converting data in a column which is Latin1 to UTF8MB4.  Things seemed to be good until we ran a data parity check and then we realized, our conversion would either replace a special character with "?" or randomly add "?" in spots.

Here is our conversion SQL:

```
    SELECT (SELECT CONVERT(CONVERT(d.actualresults USING latin1) USING utf8mb4)  FROM document d  
    WHERE d.origindocumentid = 2711460)
    FROM documentfield df
    WHERE LOWER(df.name) = 'actualresults';
```

So here is the original text (HTML Snippet)

```
<li><span style="background-color:rgb(255, 255, 0)">​<a href="https://www.land.com/perspective.req?projectId=24113&amp;docId=2711870" target="_blank">convert/import preview needs some minor ui changes</a></span></li>
```

here it is after converting:

```
<li><span style="background-color:rgb(255, 255, 0)">​?<a href="https://www.land.com/perspective.req?projectId=24113&amp;docId=2711870" target="_blank">convert/import preview needs some minor ui changes</a></span></li>
```

Notice the "?" on the first line?  Why is the convert adding in this "?"

Another example is:

So here is the original text (HTML Snippet)

```
<li><span style="background-color:rgb(255, 255, 0)">​✓<a href="https://www.land.com/perspective.req?projectId=24113&amp;docId=2711870" target="_blank">convert/import preview needs some minor ui changes</a></span></li>
```

here it is after converting:

```
<li><span style="background-color:rgb(255, 255, 0)">​?<a href="https://www.land.com/perspective.req?projectId=24113&amp;docId=2711870" target="_blank">convert/import preview needs some minor ui changes</a></span></li>
```

How can I avoid this?

```
    SELECT (SELECT CONVERT(CONVERT(d.actualresults USING latin1) USING utf8mb4)  FROM document d  
    WHERE d.origindocumentid = 2711460)
    FROM documentfield df
    WHERE LOWER(df.name) = 'actualresults';
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is wondering or if someone runs in to this, here is the answer.

```
    SELECT (SELECT CONVERT(d.actualresults USING utf8mb4)  FROM document d  
WHERE d.origindocumentid = 2711460)
FROM documentfield df
WHERE LOWER(df.name) = 'actualresults';
```